# Mysterious identity in cosimplicial $R$-module with Lie brackets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, simplicial-stuff

I have a cosimplicial $R$-module $\mathscr{A}:=(A_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and on each $A_n$ a Lie bracket $[-,-]_n:A_n\otimes A_n\to A_n$. Denote the cofaces by $d_i:A_n\to A_{n+1}$ and the codegeneracies by $s_i:A_{n+1}\to A_n$. For topological reasons, my object $\mathscr{A}$ satisfies
$$[s_ix,y]_n = s_i[x,d_iy]_{n+1}+s_i[x,d_{i+1}y]_{n+1}$$
for $x\in A_{n+1}$ and $y\in A_n$.
In particular, it is not a cosimplicial Lie algebra. Does this relation remind someone of something?